# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'InteractionCreate')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am currently trying to code my discord bot using slash commands.

I have done it like the discordjs.guide docs but apparently it cannot read the InteractionCreate.

Below I have shared my index.js file.

I have no experience in coding so please go easy on me and dumb it down as best as possible :D

```
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits, Collection, Intents, MessageAttachment, Message, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const config = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] });


//Bot Status
client.on("ready", () => {

    console.log('Ready!');

    client.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: `Wartungsarbeiten`, type: 'WATCHING' }], status: 'dnd'})
});

//Event Loader
const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

//Command Loader
client.commands = new Collection();

const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    // Set a new item in the Collection with the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    } else {
        console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
    }
}

//Command Handler and Interaction Collector
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {

    //Command Handling
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) {
        console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
        return;
    }

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }

    //Interaction Collector

    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        interaction.reply("Du hast einen Knopf gedrückt")
    }

});

client.login(config. token);
```

Pls Help

The error is in this line:

```
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
```

I am looking forward to  your responses.

Comment: What version of DJS are you using? If I'm correct, `Events` was added recently

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't running Discord.js v14 unlike I thought.